# I'm having a hard time on the solidity course

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am new on stackowerflow and also solidity.

I have to do: In function `booleanOperatorTest`, negate the variable `foo` and assign the result to variable `negation`

```js
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract OperatorTutorial {

    function booleanOperatorTest(bool foo, bool bar) public pure
        returns (bool negation, bool conjunction, bool disjunction, bool equality, bool inequality) {

        // Negate the variable "foo" and assign the result to variable "negation"
        // negation =
}
```

I tried everything but i can't pass this step, please help, thank you .

Answer (score 1):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract OperatorTutorial {

    function booleanOperatorTest(bool foo, bool bar) public pure
        returns (bool negation, bool conjunction, bool disjunction, bool equality, bool inequality) {
        negation = !foo;
 }
```

Thanks to Mert Sungur

Answer (score 0):

Example function:

```
function booleanOperatorTest(bool foo, bool bar) public pure
    returns (bool negation,bool conjunction) {

    // Negate the variable "foo" and assign the result to variable "negation"
      negation =foo;
      conjunction  = (foo && bar);
      ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract OperatorTutorial {

    function booleanOperatorTest(bool foo, bool bar) public pure
        returns (bool negation, bool conjunction, bool disjunction, bool equality, bool inequality) {

        // Negate the variable "foo" and assign the result to variable "negation"
        // negation =
           negation = !foo;
        // Use logical "and" on variables "foo" and "bar" and assign the result to variable "conjunction"
        // conjunction =
           conjunction  = (foo && bar);
        // Use logical "or" on variables "foo" and "bar" and assign the result to variable "disjunction"
        // disjunction =
           disjunction = (foo || bar);
        // Make sure variable "equality" is true when "foo" and "bar" are equal and is false otherwise.
        // equality =
           equality = (foo  == bar);
        // Make sure variable "inequality" is true when "foo" and "bar" are not equal and is false otherwise.
        // inequality =
           inequality = (foo != bar);
    }
```